# How to check if a variable I assigned to an item within a list of lists and then implemented that variable into a list IS inside of that list?

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

I created a variable that is assigned to an item within a list of lists, then assigned that same variable into a different list. Whenever I am checking to see if that variable is inside of that list, it doesn't check the name 'A6' it only checks the value of those variables assigned.

```
board = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'] , ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'] , ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

A1 = board[0][0]
A2 = board[0][1]
A3 = board[0][2]
A4 = board[0][3]
A5 = board[0][4]
A6 = board[0][5]
A7 = board[0][6]
A8 = board[0][7]
A9 = board[0][8]

B1 = board[1][0]
B2 = board[1][1]
B3 = board[1][2]
B4 = board[1][3]
B5 = board[1][4]
B6 = board[1][5]
B7 = board[1][6]
B8 = board[1][7]
B9 = board[1][8]

A = [A1 , A2 , A3 , A4 , A5 , A6 , A7 , A8 , A9]

user_input = input('input stone coordinate: ')

def checks_coord():
    
    for i in A:
        
        if i == user_input:
            
            print('true')
    
checks_coord()
```

I tried using the for loop to check if the user input was the same as one of the variables inside of the list 'A'. For example, I would input 'A6' and it wouldn't print true, yet whenever I entered in '.', it printed true.

Comment: Why do you expect the `A` list to contain the string `"A6"`? It contains the value of the _variable_ `A6`, and the value of this variable is the string `"."`.

Comment: Have you tried printing out `A` and `i`? Because `A` does not contain the variable _names_, but the actual _values_.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
A = [ ... , A6, ... ]
```

What you wanted to write was

```
A = [ ... , (0, 5), ... ]
```

---

If users will refer to a row as `A` instead of as `0`,
then you will need a way to map back and forth between them.
You *could* use a `dict`.
Or you may find that

```
    chr(n + ord('A'))
```

is a convenient way to turn the integer `n` into a `str`.

The converse operation for input string `ch` is

```
    ord(ch) - ord('A')
```